# Adding checkbox to datagridview column header, not aligning properly

Tags: vb.net, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

Im trying to add a checkbox to a specific datagridview column header, I found some code online to help but it's not aligning properly and I'm not really sure how to fix it.

Below is an image of the problem and the code, any help would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. I think it might be something to do with properties but I've played around with them but not been successful.

[image]

```
Private checkboxHeader231 As CheckBox
Private Sub show_chkBox()
Dim rect As Rectangle = DataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(columnIndexOfCheckBox, -1, True)
' set checkbox header to center of header cell. +1 pixel to position 
rect.Y = 3
rect.X = rect.Location.X + 8 + (rect.Width / 4)
checkboxHeader231 = New CheckBox()
With checkboxHeader231
    .BackColor = Color.Transparent
End With

checkboxHeader231.Name = "checkboxHeader1"
checkboxHeader231.Size = New Size(18, 18)
checkboxHeader231.Location = rect.Location
AddHandler checkboxHeader231.CheckedChanged, AddressOf checkboxHeader231_CheckedChanged
DataGridView1.Controls.Add(checkboxHeader231)
End Sub

Private Sub checkboxHeader231_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
Dim headerBox As CheckBox = DirectCast(DataGridView1.Controls.Find("checkboxHeader1", True)(0), CheckBox)
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    row.Cells(columnIndexOfCheckBox).Value = headerBox.Checked
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What is this comment "    ' set checkbox header to center of header cell. +1 pixel to position @

Comment: I forgot to un-delete the piece of code that was there before I uploaded it, one sec I'll sort it out!

Answer (score 2):

This is my first entry, but I think this is what youre looking for. I tested it and it worked on my datagrid. You were using the width for the rectangle, youll need it for the column width instead. I set the column header to 4, but you would replace the 4 with your column you want to use I put it in two ways, one with a four loop, the other just as single lines. Tell me if this worked for you:

```
Dim rect As Rectangle = DataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(4, -1, True) ' replace 4
        rect.Y = 3

        Dim sum = DataGridView1.Columns(0).Width

        'for this area write a for loop to find the width of each column except for the last line which you manually do
        '
        '
        'For i As Integer = 1 To 4 - 1 Step 1  ' replace 4
        'sum = sum + DataGridView1.Columns(i).Width
        'Next

        sum = sum + DataGridView1.Columns(1).Width
        sum = sum + DataGridView1.Columns(2).Width
        sum = sum + DataGridView1.Columns(3).Width
        ' stop here and add the last line by hand here

        sum = sum + (DataGridView1.Columns(4).Width / 2) + 35 ' used in both cases ' replace 4
        rect.X = sum

        checkboxHeader231 = New CheckBox()
        With checkboxHeader231
            .BackColor = Color.Transparent
        End With

        checkboxHeader231.Name = "checkboxHeader1"
        checkboxHeader231.Size = New Size(18, 18)
        checkboxHeader231.Location = rect.Location
        AddHandler checkboxHeader231.CheckedChanged, AddressOf checkboxHeader231_CheckedChanged
        DataGridView1.Controls.Add(checkboxHeader231)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private headerBox As CheckBox
Private Sub show_checkBox()
        Dim checkboxHeader As CheckBox = New CheckBox()
        Dim rect As Rectangle = PendingApprovalServiceListingDataGridView.GetCellDisplayRectangle(4, -1, True)
        rect.X = 20
        rect.Y = 12
        With checkboxHeader
            .BackColor = Color.Transparent
        End With
        checkboxHeader.Name = "checkboxHeader"
        checkboxHeader.Size = New Size(14, 14)
        checkboxHeader.Location = rect.Location
        AddHandler checkboxHeader.CheckedChanged, AddressOf checkboxHeader_CheckedChanged
        PendingApprovalServiceListingDataGridView.Controls.Add(checkboxHeader)
    End Sub
    Private Sub checkboxHeader_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        headerBox = DirectCast(PendingApprovalServiceListingDataGridView.Controls.Find("checkboxHeader", True)(0), CheckBox)
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In PendingApprovalServiceListingDataGridView.Rows
            row.Cells(0).Value = headerBox.Checked
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.